# Access 2003 under Virtual PC: can I migrate to real PC? Or buy Office 2010?

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-virtual-pc, microsoft-access

27" iMac running win7 under bootcamp (slick! ). I have Access 2003 program with files linked through ODBC used by 4 installations (all with Access 2003 installed). I want to buy Access 2010 and try it under virtual PC (under Bootcamp). Will it work (since I have to install the ODBC drivers)? If I decide after this trial that I like what it does, can I then install it under the Windows 7 bootcamp partition (with or without uninstalling the virtual PC) without using up the 2nd allowed installation? Also, I see that MS allows an Office Pro 2010 trial download good for 60 days. Would this work in Windows 7 Virtual PC and would it be a better way to go, followed by a legitimate purchase of Access 2010 for the Windows 7?

This is not an Access programming question--I realize there may be some tweaks necessary in the program to run it under 2010 and I can handle that part.

Comment: "(slick!)" made my day.

Comment: If you're running Bootcamp, you're booting into real Windows, so why would you need VirtualPC?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to download the 60-day Trial version and test it in your virtual machine. Once you've verified that it'll do what you want it to do, then you can install the new version on your Win7 partition and buy the product key.

I would definitely not purchase it until you've completely tested it with the Trial version.